# jQuery: how to fade in permanent website elements only once?

Tags: jquery, animation, conditional-statements

The website I'm building has a few elements that are the same on every page, such as a logo, a menu, a copyright notice, and so on.

I want to fade them in once the visitor loads any of the website's pages, and never replay the fade-in effect for any other pages the visitor may arrive to.

I know making the site AJAXy would be one of the solutions, but for certain number of reasons having separate pages would be preferable in this particular case.

Maybe there's a way to check the opacity of an element (from a previous page?) and **if** it's 100% to keep it as is, **otherwise** fade in the element - but I'm not sure how it can be done. Or - perhaps, if there's a way to check **if** the visitor arrived to a page from the same main domain name, in which case the opacity of all the elements should be equal 100%, **otherwise** they should be fade in?

I would appreciate a practical solution!

Someone else on StackOverflow wrote "just use a cookie" in a similar case, and a solution was accepted, but no actual example of a cookie was provided, and that would be most helpful if someone could do it.

Comment: The "just use a cookie" answer is the way to go. [`$.cookie`](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) makes this extremely simple.

Comment: Thank you Matt. Could you please show me how it's done? The actual code? I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a uniquie cookie value for each element that loads and check it on every page to determine whether to fade-in or not.

http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.cookie.js.txt

```
var loaded = $.cookie('loaded');
loaded = (typeof(loaded) == 'string') ? loaded.split('|') : [];
if($.inArray('unique_key', loaded) == -1) {
  alert('first load');
  $('#element').fadeIn();
  loaded.push('unique_key');
  $.cookie('loaded', loaded.join('|'));
} else {
  alert('subsequent load');
  $('#element').show();
}
```

Comment: Devmatt, this is helpful, but could you please show me how that plugin can be implemented to achieve the result I want?

Comment: This looks very good, but when I test it, it doesn't work. I may be doing something wrong. I downloaded jquery.cookie.js file and registered it in my header, I created #element div in the body, I wrapped the snippet of code that you wrote in the script tag and document-ready event, and placed it the header below the script registration. Nothing happens, the #element just stays there, without fading in even the first time. What am I doing wrong? Maybe you could put together a quick demo on jsfiddle for example? I would be very grateful!

Comment: Try adding alerts into the if statement and check firebug that there aren't any errors being thrown.

Comment: Could you show me the code with the alert please? (I'm a beginner.)

Comment: Thank you. I reset the browser, pasted the new code and I tested it. No alerts, no fade in effect. Help please?

Comment: Yes. "Loaded is null" in this line: loaded = loaded.split('|');

Comment: Please take a look at this example. http://cybart.com/cookietest/  I think I'm implementing the script correctly, but unfortunately it doesn't work. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Code updated. I wasn't checking the return value of the cookie and that was causing issues when there hasn't been a cookie set yet. `loaded = (typeof(loaded) == 'string') ? loaded.split('|') : [];`

Comment: Now I can see the "first load" comment. But the fadeIn effect doesn't play. Please take a look: http://cybart.com/cookietest/ What should I do differently?

Comment: @Dimitri Vorontzov - Sorry, I was obviously not thinking clearly when I wrote the above snippet of code. I've updated it and it's working fine now.

Comment: Not really. :-( it shows "first load" and "subsequent load" alerts but it doesn't play the fadeIn effect! But we're getting there! Just one tony step more!

Comment: In order for it to fade in it needs to start out hidden

Comment: DUH! :-) YES! It works now! Thank you Devmatt! Could you stay with me a few minuites longer until test it with the main website? I may have a couple more questions...

Comment: I'm going to be off now. If this answer helped, please mark it as the answer to your question.

Comment: YES! TEN THOUSAND TIMES YES! It worked on my website, too. Thank you Devmatt, you've solved a HUGE problem for me!

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the client's referrer (using JavaScript) - if it contains your domain you know the user has come from another page on your site.

Something like... (untested)

```
if (document.referrer.indexOf('www.mydomain.com' === -1) {
  // show animation
}
```

This would show the animation for every time the user visited your site from another location - whereas with the cookie approach you would know for the lifetime of the cookie if the user had been there before.

Also, this approach might need modifying to use a case-inesnsitive regex as I think indexOf is case sensitive and someone may have typed your URL wrong

Comment: This is promising. How can I test it with alert box?

Comment: alert(document.referrer.match(/stackoverflow/i) ? 'Previous page Stack Overflow' : 'Previous page something else')

Comment: regarding the above - be careful with special characters (e.g. period ( . ) ) in the regex

Answer (score 0):

you could "just use a cookie" to flag that the animation has been played.  Haha just saw the last part of your post.  I'm a fan of this library [jQuery Cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.cookie.js.txt).  Also, I wrapped it in a data provider JS class like so:

```
mycompany.data.cache = {
    grab: function(key){
        return $.evalJSON($.cookie(key));
    },
    push: function(key, value){
        $.cookie(key, $.toJSON(value), {path: '/', expires: 7});
    },
    remove: function(key){
        $.cookie(key, null);
    }
};
```

So you could write

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    bool animationPlayed = mycompany.data.cache.grab('animationPlayed');

    if(!animationPlayed)
        //play animation...
    else
        //do something else...
});
```

Comment: This may be a good solution, but could you please explain to me more specifically how this code should be placed? Should it all be just wrapped in one event handler or should it be placed in different parts of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your backend framework is, but in ASP.NET you could check `Session.IsNewSession` and add a class to those elements (i.e. `firstTimeFadeIn`) if it's true...  The jQuery code to run the fade in on all items of that class would be easy enough.

Comment: Thank you Shane. I'm working with PHP, but I want the kind of solution that wouldn't depend on the server.